# how to correctly sscanf a decimal to a char

Tags: c

PVS-Studio gave me a warning about this :

```
char c;
sscanf(line, "%d", &c);
```

I changed %d to %c but this created a bug because "c" now contains the ASCII value of the number and not the decimal one, so I went back to "%d".

So what's the correct specifier to ? is there another solution ?

Comment: `char c;
sscanf(line, "%d", &c);` is *already* a bug, and a really, really bad memory-corrupting one at that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple solutions for your problem:

- you can specify the correct destination type:

  ```
  char c;
  if (sscanf(line, "%hhd", &c) == 1) {
      /* successful conversion */
      ...
  }
  ```
- you can use an intermediary variable:

  ```
  char c;
  int cc;
  if (sscanf(line, "%d", &cc) == 1) {
      /* successful conversion */
      c = cc;
      ...
  }
  ```
- you can use different conversion function:

  ```
  #include <stdlib.h>
  ...
  char c;
  c = atoi(line);  // no error handling, return 0 if not a number
  ```

Note however that in all cases, if the numeric value converted by `sscanf()` or `atoi()` is outside the range of type `char`, the behavior is undefined. Most current system will just use the low order byte of the conversion result, but the C Standard does not guarantee it.

Answer (score 5):

`c` is a `char`. You asked to scan an `int`. PVS-Studio did right in warning you. Change the type of `c` to `int` and scan for a `%d`.

Comment: the char is from a legacy header, I can't change it.

Comment: Scan to another variable and copy that to c. Don't scan directly to c as this may lead to you writing to memory you shouldn't.